# perl data dumper: how handle string with backslash

Tags: perl

how do I "dumper" a string with backslash, without showing it as double backslash?

This:

```
my $str = 'a\b';
print Dumper $str;
```

will output: 
`$VAR1 = 'a\\b';` instead `$VAR1 = 'a\b';`

As you can imagine, this will cause "shock" during debug session.

Is there a way to dump the string with single backslash?

Comment: Just a question, do we need `Dumper` to print `scalar` values?

Comment: Is `print "$str\n";` does not do what you ask for? `Data::Dumper` is more fit for complex data structures.

Comment: Why would it cause "shock"? You notice that the first time, and every time after that you know what's going on.

Comment: @ vkk05 and Polar Bear. you are right, no need to dump a simple scalar as $str above, but this is an example only, to simplify things. 

In the real code, I was "dumping" complex hashes which one of them consist backslash as value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are infinitely many ways to create the three-character string `a\b`, including the following:

- `'a\b'`
- `'a\\b'`
- `"a\\b"`
- `"a\x5Cb"`
- `join(chr(0x5B), qw( a b ))`
- `pack('H*', '615C62')`

Data::Dumper has no way to know what code was used to create the string. DD is taked to generate valid Perl code that would create the provided string if executed, and that's exactly what it does when it produces `'a\\b'` for `a\b`. Backslashes (`\`) must sometimes be escaped in single-quoted string literals, so DD always escapes it to keep things simple and consistent (just like I do).

If you don't want to generate Perl code, don't use Data::Dumper.

Comment: thanks for the information. I expected that single quote to take string as it is without handling anything. I was just looking a way to bypass this behavior, if not possible, than we'll just have to live with it.

Comment: Re "*take string as it is without handling anything*",  That's not true. You're not expecting `a\b` (which wouldn't be valid Perl code). The string must be transformed into a string literal; you're just disagreeing as to which string literal should be generated (`'a\b'` vs `'a\\b'`). Either way, a transformation occurs.